# Is there a way to dynamically change parameters in parameters.yml Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer

I am new to symfony, and I need to add a method that will automatically send mails to a different user each time using a different admin mail/password. I am using swiftmailer and I know that *config.yml* takes parameters directly from parameters.yml so my question is :
how to set different `mailer_user` and `mailer_password` each time a new admin connects without having to manually change it?
Can I directly extract data from my database?

Comment: Welcome to SO! There is a better chance that you will get a high quality answer if you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Is creating EmailUser entity in database an option? Thats the easiest way to delegate dynamic config values in your application

Comment: Are you looking to have the new admin appear as the sender of the email? The sender is different from the `mailer_user`.

Comment: Why do you want to put something in the core configuration of your application that changes so frequently? There is no reason to read the configuration for sending mails from that file - it would be better to configure it directly without coupling to service definitions

Comment: Okay so to clarify things :                                                                                                             I need a way to automatically send Emails when a ticket is created , the Email is automatically generated. But, I have different users who can access the application and each user has a different Email address and some even have a different form ( I don't know if this changes anything ) So let's say I have user A and user B , User A has this Email **UserA@exemple.com** and user B has **usr@ex.ex2** how can I make them both send Email using their addresses.

Comment: And I need to add that I can only test on my Email address : gmail.com ( I am a trainee after all and I am not allowed to access their database ). @geoB is there a way to make the admin appear as the sender ? ( Using his mail ) Because when i tried to change the `-> setFrom()`  without modifying mailer_user no mail is sent .

Comment: @NicoHaase How to configurate it directly please ? are you talking about creating a transport object ?

Comment: @TZiebura I have a **user database** and I can access each user Email and his hashed password . And the only way to make it possible is to make the user type his Password each time he wants to send an email ( and compare it to the hash ) which is not practical in my case.

Comment: @hakamkoubaa perhaps store email account password in the User entity encrypted using one of [those algorithms](https://blog.storagecraft.com/5-common-encryption-algorithms/) then when they need to send email just restore the encrypted value to plain value

Comment: @TZiebura I assume you don't have a good idea about hash functions but for your personal informations, hash functions are unidirectional and from **F(x)** you can never get **x** so unfortunately it's not possible .

Comment: I don't know anything about the current configuration, but it should be simple to use some variable value instead of `mailer_user` exactly when you need it

Comment: @hakamkoubaa I am talking about encryption, not hashing :)